# Has Anyone found a comfortable way to wear your mobile device when exercising?

Tags: running, weightlifting, exercise, crossfit

I hate to wear armbands when working out and my headphones seem to get snagged.  Has anyone used this shirt before? [image]

Comment: You could get bluetooth earphones. You wouldn't have the wires flying around then.

Answer (score 3):

I use this waistpack from Nike. It's literally just a small fanny pack. It's just big enough to fit my phone (Galaxy S6) comfortably but it can fit my wallet in it as well. I also keep my keys on a small carabiner, so I can clip them onto the waistband if I'm just walking around. I usually just have my headphones' wire behind me, down my back, and the waistpack turned around so that the phone is on the small of my back.

$20 for it is a little expensive but I find a lot of use out of it. I use it mainly for listening to music while weightlifting, but if I'm playing tennis or any other sports that involve running around or just biking, I prefer using it over having stuff bouncing around in my pockets.

[image]

http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/lean-running-waistpack/pid-10313873/pgid-10313874

Comment: A camelbak or any bag is the best. Only carry a phone on looong runs, rides, trails so this is the best for me too

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I don't think there's any comfortable way to wear a large and rather hefty piece of electronics on your body if you're bouncing about.

For running and lifting, I have [a small mp3 player](http://amzn.to/1QCsR7A) that I plug some behind-the-ear headphones into. Beyond the tiny profile, I also like it because I'm not distracted by notifications. My workout time is mine, if something is that *that* important someone can drive over to the gym or track me down on the streets. Otherwise it can wait.

For other sports where I want a phone for emergency use or to stay connected with friends (snowboarding, etc) I park my phone in my jacket pocket and use [a bluetooth controller](http://amzn.to/1Uda6dn). My phone stays protected from crashes and the environment, and I can control things with a gloved finger.

Comment: I totally agree. I don't understand why some people want to say connected 100% of the time (even when running). Running is my Me-Time. disconnected from everything stressrelated: Just me and the road.

Comment: I turn notifications off but I like to have the option of turning it back on. Also having my entire music catalogue and not needing yet another device (along with the GPS tracker!!)

Answer (score 1):

I stopped bothering for the exact same reasons above, too clunky. A good solution might be a running jumper with a pocket at the top;

[image: Adidas cheat running hoody]

Answer (score 1):

For carrying my tablet, I actually had my mother sew me up a small backpack that slings across my back. It holds snugly to my back, so there's no real bouncing to worry about, and she made it in a way where I can rotate it around my body for when I don't feel like contorting to reach it. For the tablet I own with a strap on the back, I'll sometimes just carry it in my hand, switching hands when one arm gets tired. It adds an additional small workout and keeps it handy (it's also in a shock-resistant case so I don't have to worry about dropping it or falling).

For headphones, I used to just use cheap Dollar Store ones. The wires were long enough to reach from the backpack and the low cost meant that replacement them every half year or so was a small impact to me. I now use a Bluetooth headset I picked up at Aldis for about $15. Fewer wires to worry about, although it does mean one more thing to keep charged.